# How to automatically create neat C comment blocks while typing?

Tags: comment, editing, c, development

Some code editors such as eclipse automatically form neat blocks when you start typing a multi-line comment:

[image]

Is there some package or another way to do this in emacs too?

**Edit:** To clarify: I do *not* want a key-combination that inserts a comment block. I want a comment block to be automatically created when I press `RET` after `/*`.

Comment: Did you check this similar question?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6578421/4780877

Comment: @EmacsUser: Yeah. But that's not what I want. I don't want just a snippet or the feature to comment an already written region.

Comment: See the manual for [Multiple Lines of Comments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dLine-Comments.html).

Comment: @Dan: That's pretty close, but it does not automatically insert the closing `*/`

Comment: Are the `*`'s signs at the middle lines are necessary or are purely cosmetic? Is closing automatically the comment by `*/ ` when you start by `/*`  the feature you are requesting to have?

Comment: @Name The `*` signs are not strictly required, but nice to have.

Comment: I just looked into abbrev-mode for this, and it seems to have two problems: first, that you need the triggering abbreviation to be a word, not `/*`; second, I don't think you can have the abbrev indent multiple lines properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below code works fine from my brief testing in a `c-mode` buffer:

- After typing `/*`, hit `M-j`, the default binding for `indent-new-comment-line` (and the default binding for `c-indent-new-comment-line` in `c-mode`). If it is the first comment line the closing closing characters `*/` will be auto-inserted.
- Hitting `M-j` more times with insert more comment lines with the `*` prefix. This is the in-built behavior of `c-indent-new-comment-line`/`indent-new-comment-line` functions. Check out the [Multiple lines of comments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dLine-Comments.html) documentation.
- An extra nugget in the below code ensures that there is at least one space between the `*` on each comment line and the comment.

```el
(defun my-prettify-c-block-comment (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let* ((first-comment-line (looking-back "/\\*\\s-*.*"))
         (star-col-num (when first-comment-line
                         (save-excursion
                           (re-search-backward "/\\*")
                           (1+ (current-column))))))
    (apply orig-fun args)
    (when first-comment-line
      (save-excursion
        (newline)
        (dotimes (cnt star-col-num)
          (insert " "))
        (move-to-column star-col-num)
        (insert "*/"))
      (move-to-column star-col-num) ; comment this line if using bsd style
      (insert "*") ; comment this line if using bsd style
     ))
  ;; Ensure one space between the asterisk and the comment
  (when (not (looking-back " "))
    (insert " ")))
(advice-add 'c-indent-new-comment-line :around #'my-prettify-c-block-comment)
;; (advice-remove 'c-indent-new-comment-line #'my-prettify-c-block-comment)
```

---

For instance, after evaluating the above code, I get the below on typing: `/*` `M-j` `First comment line` `M-j` `Second comment line`. *The ▮ indicates the cursor location at the end of typing.*

```c
/*
 * First comment line
 * Second comment line▮
 */
```

Testing offset comment block ..

With cursor after the semicolon, typing: `/*` `M-j` `Test offset comment` gives the below. *The ▮ indicates the cursor location at the end of typing.*

```c
#include<stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("Hello World"); /*
                          * Test offset comment▮  
                          */                                 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, *but* if I have `(setq c-default-style "bsd" c-basic-offset 4)` in my `init.el`, this happens: http://i.imgur.com/KMLx6Ll.gif Any idea?

Comment: Removing `(move-to-column star-col-num) (insert "*")` from the above solution will fix that for you. I don't code in C, so I haven't investigated what variables are set by `"bsd"` style.

Comment: Using this code with Dafny mode from https://github.com/boogie-org/boogie-friends, I get ` /*` for each newline rather than ` *`.